# Representing the database and it's relationships

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an MySQL database. It contains many tables and relationships. Is there a software or is there a way to implement it, so I would get a representation similar to this:

[image]

Or I'll just need to do it by hand?

Comment: MySQL Workbench can do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql Workbench has this feature.

Also you can do it in phpmyadmin :)

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin has such a view using their designer feature.

Comment: Oh, that's just awesome, how could I not know it.